# Chromedriver: How to disable Google Chrome Helper

Tags: python, macos, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running 10 chromedriver browsers on a mac, each using 1 tab, but which somehow have spawned 98 Google Chrome Helpers. These helpers are eating up my available memory, and severely limiting what hardware I can run these tests on.

The internet seems to be in mass agreement that google chrome helper can be disabled by going to /settings/content settings/plugins, then selecting the "Click to play" option.

However, that option does not appear to exist in the current version of chrome. Instead the three options are:

```
Run all plugin content 
Detect and run important plugin content
Let me choose when to run plugin content (which is assume is the equivalent)
```

To attempt to get the latter option as my default setting I created a blank folder, then ran this in the terminal

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/Users/User/Documents/Python/chome_helper_blank_folder
```

I can confirm the settings I change in this instance stick, and opening up a new instance in this fashion launches with the settings I last established.

I am getting this error on launch, but it doesn't appear to be affecting :

```
2016-08-23 08:55:48.149 Google Chrome[556:16791] NSWindow warning: adding an unknown subview: <FullSizeContentView: 0x7fc703e84f80>. Break on NSLog to debug.
2016-08-23 08:55:48.149 Google Chrome[556:16791] Call stack:
(
    "+callStackSymbols disabled for performance reasons"
(
```

In addition to the above setting, I navigated to

```
 chrome://plugins/
```

and disabled the 4 plugins displaying.

Unfortunately, 3 chrome helpers per browser still appear at browser launch.

When I use the following python commands, chrome launches with the settings I established above, but the chrome helpers are still there as well.

```
chome_helper_blank_folder_path = "/Users/User/Documents/Python/chome_helper_blank_folder"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir="+chome_helper_blank_folder_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Is there any way to get rid of google chrome helper with chromedriver?

Comment: I want to know about this. Does anyone know?